# using telebot in callback_query_handler with two filters func and state custom im trying to store state but i get TypeError: 'NoneType'

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

Using telebot in callback_query_handler with two filters func and state custom im trying to store state but i get TypeError: 'NoneType'

***data['model'] = call.data**
TypeError: '**NoneType**' object does not support item assignment*

I dont know why data is NoneType

```
 ...
state_storage = StateMemoryStorage()

MODELS = ['ROAD', 'SPORTTOURIST']
MARKS = ['YAMAHA', 'HONDA']

class MyStates(StatesGroup):
    model = State()
    mark = State()

def models_motorcycle():
    return telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=[
            [
                telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(MODELS[0], callback_data=MODELS[0]),
                telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(MODELS[1], callback_data=MODELS[1]),
            ]
        ]
    )

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_filter(message):
    bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, MyStates.model, message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Select motorcycle model', reply_markup=models_motorcycle())


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in MODELS, state=MyStates.model)
def callback_query_model(call):
    bot.set_state(call.from_user.id, MyStates.mark, call.message.chat.id)
    with bot.retrieve_data(call.message.from_user.id, call.message.chat.id) as data:
        # print(f'trying to save model data {call.data}')
        data['model'] = call.data
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Select motorcycle mark', reply_markup=marks_motorcycle())
```

Answer (score 0):

Author haven't explain how he solved a problem. In my case it was because of `call.message.from_user.id`.
You must write just `bot.retrieve_data(call.message.chat.id)`.
Also, use `async bot.retrieve_data(call.message.chat.id)`, if you apply `async`.

Answer (score -1):

i found problem. It was in block `bot.retrieve_data(call.message.from_user.id, call.message.chat.id)`

I incorrectly accessed json elements

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).