# Python, telebot. How to combine callback query handler and states?

Tags: python, state, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, telebot

I want to use states inside callback handler block, but supposingly have some problems with retrieving data.

Here are no normal traceback.
I get only `2023-07-18 14:33:00,497 (async_telebot.py:542 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "__enter__"`

Spent a lot of time for searching and find only one similiar question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/q/74185722/19160462](https://stackoverflow.com)
But there author of question doesn't explain how he had solved it.

```
import asyncio
import os
from telebot.asyncio_handler_backends import State, StatesGroup
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from telebot.async_telebot import AsyncTeleBot, asyncio_filters, StateMemoryStorage
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

#outer modules
from main_operations import calc_profit, get_attr, build_menu
from apsched import send_message_interval 

class States(StatesGroup):
    prof_price = State()
    prof_nm = State()

async def telegram_bot():
    state_storage = StateMemoryStorage()
    bot = AsyncTeleBot(os.getenv('TG_TEST_TOKEN'), state_storage=state_storage)
    
    #create inline menu of buttons with id's to be choosen
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id in users, commands=['profit'])
    async def command_profit(message):
        nm_ids = get_attr('nmId')  # return list of ids
        button_list = [InlineKeyboardButton(nm, callback_data=nm) for nm in nm_ids]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list, n_cols=3)) #just build menu
        #set first state  
        await bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, States.prof_nm, message.chat.id)
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Choose product", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    #here we want to take call_data with id, record it and go to the next step
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True, state=States.prof_nm)
    async def get_callback(callback):
        await bot.set_state(callback.message.from_user.id, States.prof_price, callback.message.chat.id)
        await bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Write a price')
        #probably, problem is here in bot.retrieve_data
        with bot.retrieve_data(callback.message.from_user.id, callback.message.chat.id) as data:
             data['prof_nm'] = callback.data
        print('retrieved!') #never seen

    #final stage
    @bot.message_handler(state=States.prof_price)
    async def click_profit(message):
        with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
            nm = data['name']
            price = message.text()
        profit = calc_profit(nm, price) 
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, profit)
        await bot.delete_state(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id)
    
    #another command to check am i using aptscheduler and async mode right in combination with other parts
    #just print something every 10sec
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id in users, commands=['info'])
        async def get_info(message):
            scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')
            scheduler.add_job(send_message_interval, trigger='interval', seconds=10, kwargs={'bot': bot})
            scheduler.start()
    
    #two row below is inside telegtam_bot(), there are a shift, then i copy it back
    bot.add_custom_filter(asyncio_filters.StateFilter(bot))
    await bot.polling(skip_pending=True)


users = [my_chat_id]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(telegram_bot())
```

Expected sequence of actions:

1. User enters the command - `/profit`
2. Bot displays buttons corresponding to a certain list with product ids
3. User selects the product id
4. Bot asks for a price
5. User enters the price
6. Bot displays to the user the result of processing a certain function `calc_profit(id,price)`

First I used `register_next_step handler` and everything was ok. But after it was required to enter a command working on schedule. I decided to use `apscheduler` and `asynchio`. It turned out that the `asynchio` is not compatible with `register_next_step handler`. Then I decided to implement my plan through `States`.

Now it seems i have some problem in "callback" part. `bot.retrieve_data` is not executed correctly.

P.S. I realise there are a lot of ways to perform a task and honestly confused by them. Maybe telebot is not suitable for my task or in general it's not the best lib, or i must choose another methods. Will be grateful for any feedback with some general ideas, how to do better creating telegram bot.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
There are actually several mistakes:
inside `get_callback()`:

1. Need to add async to `retrieve_data`
2. Not use `callback.message.from_user.id` inside retrieve data. That's a bot id.
   So it must be:

```
async with bot.retrieve_data(callback.message.chat.id) as data:
    data['prof_nm'] = callback.data
```

3. Same `async` mistake in `calc_profit`, must be:
   `async with bot.retrieve_data(callback.message.chat.id) as data:`
4. Typo: `nm = data['name']` -
   `nm = data['prof_nm']` instead, of course